# multiple select in 2 dimensional array in php

Tags: php, select

In PHP, I am having 2 array

```
$ex1 = array(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h);
$ex2 = array(c,e,f);
```

Here how can I integrate this with multiple select option in PHP page

Here ex1 is the multiple select array like

```
<select multiple name=slt[]>

</select>
```

And ex2 values are the chosen listing options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
<?php

$ex1 = array('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h');
$ex2 = array('c','e','f');

echo "<select multiple name=slt[]>";

    foreach($ex1 as $val){
        //in_array() checks if value from 1st array ($val) is present
        //anywhere in the second array ($ex2)
        //if yes, that option will be selected. I'm using ternary operator 
        //here instead of if statement
        $selected = (in_array($val,$ex2))?' selected':'';
        echo "<option value='".$val."'$selected>".$val."</option>";
    }

echo "</select>";


?>
```

**[PHP Demo](http://codepad.org/OseqhOVx)**

**[Output Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mnBQ9/1/)**

Comment: @user2688251 You're welcome, added a bit of comment to read if you're interested to learn.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about what you want to do, but here's an idea :

```
$ex1 = array("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h");

echo "<select multiple>";              
foreach( $ex1 as $value ){
    echo "<option value='$value'>$value</option>";
}

echo "</select>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running it:

```
<?php
$ex1 = array('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h');
$ex2 = array('c','e','f');
?>
<select multiple name=slt[]>
<?php
foreach ($ex1 as $option) {
    $active = false;
    foreach($ex2 as $selected){
        if($option == $selected){
            $active = true;
        }
    }
?>
    <option value="<?php echo $option; ?>" <?php if($active===true) echo "selected"; ?>><?php echo $option; ?></option>
<?php
}
?>
</select>
```

Comment: First array is the fields. And the $ex2 array values are selected fields. So it must highlight here